# Testflight or coupon codes for review websites

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, testflight

We will soon be launching the first version of our app. We want to write to a lot of app review websites about our app and want to give a free test version to them. There are 2 options:

1. Add them as external testers to TestFlight.
2. Give them a coupon/voucher code to download the app.

Problem with option #2 is that there is a limit of 100 codes available. Is it allowed to just give review websites a TestFlight version or is there some rule or limitations to who you can add as external tester (for a paid app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's no rules on iTunes Connect help](http://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdc42b26b8) to say who you can give TestFlight access to.

Giving access to TestFlight to reviewers might be an advantage, besides the promotional code limit, as the app doesn't need to be live for reviewing to take place (or the review can be of a new, unreleased app version).